# Fill the lower part with lines for tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

Using the tcolorbox package to produce exercises for a textbook, I use the option `invisible` to let space for students for writing their solutions.

For that, I want to let the blank space of the lower part, filled by horizontal lines, to let the students write comfortably. This must be done for the long exercises, taking more than one page, too, of course.
 How can I do this?

Note that we can obtain a grid with the option `help lines`, but this option induces a grid not lines... So can we put a similar option what gives only horizontal and not vertical lines ?

I give a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
    segmentation style={double=white,draw=green!20!black,double distance=1pt,solid},
    lowerbox=invisible,
    savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    #2
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{Ex1}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}

\tcblower
The derivative is:
\vspace*{5cm}   %% more space on solution for clarity
\[f^\prime(x) = \cos((\sin x)^2) 2\sin x \cos x.\]
\end{exercise}

\tcbstoprecording
\end{document}
```

and its compilation:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `lowerbox` is not an special `node` like `title`, `interior` or `frame`, but it's the space below `segmentation` node, therefore you can use `\tcbsebmentstate` switch to know if the corresponding box fragment contains or not the lower part. Following code shows a possible solution using `tcbsegmentstate` inside `etoolbox` conditionals. By the way, `etoolbox` is already loaded by `tcolorbox`, you don't need to charge it explicitly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    underlay unbroken and first={%
        \ifnumequal{\tcbsegmentstate}{1}{
            \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \draw[help lines, ystep=\baselineskip, xstep=\linewidth] (segmentation.west) grid (frame.south east);
            \end{tcbclipinterior}
        }{} 
    },
    underlay middle and last={%
        \ifnumequal{\tcbsegmentstate}{1}{
            \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \draw[help lines, ystep=\baselineskip, xstep=\linewidth] (segmentation.west) grid (frame.south east);
            \end{tcbclipinterior}
        }{\ifnumequal{\tcbsegmentstate}{2}{
            \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \draw[help lines, ystep=\baselineskip, xstep=\linewidth] (frame.north west) grid (frame.south east);
            \end{tcbclipinterior}
            }{} 
        }
    },
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[1]
\tcblower
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which does exactly my purpose, for this example. The use of the `\tcbsegmentstate` macro is ingenuous, but I don't understand very well its use... I will read the doc about the macros `underlay unbroken`, `underlay middle` etc.. Many thanks

Comment: Othe thing please. Your use of `xstep` and `ystep` is beautiful for `help line` but I haven't found it in the doc of the package ! curious !

Comment: These are `TiKZ` options and commands. You can find them into `pgfmanual`